# Why do theorems involving $V(p)$ always come in the form $\sum_{p<Q}pV(p)<B$

Tags: nt.number-theory

The quantity

$$V(p)=\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\left|\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\n \equiv r\mathrm{mod}(p)}}^N a_n-p^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n
\right|^2$$

has been well studied by many number theorists (see [this survey](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183540922) for example), and all of the inequalities I have seen involving it have come in the form

\begin{equation}
\sum_{p<Q}pV(p)<B\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Where $Q=Q(N)$ limits the growth on $p$ and $B=B(N)$ is the actual bound. Examining $\frac{p^2V(p)}{N^2}$ we see that

$$\frac{p^2V(p)}{N^2}=\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\left|\frac{p}{N}\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\n \equiv r\mathrm{mod}(p)}}^N a_n-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n
\right|^2$$

and if we assume that the quantities

\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{p}{N}\sum_{\substack{n=1 \\n \equiv r\mathrm{mod}(p)}}^N a_n,\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\tag{2}
\end{equation}

exists then we have that $V'(p)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{p^2V(p)}{N^2}$ exists. This quantity is easier to study since it is generally bounded/small as $N\to\infty$ which can be seen from the fact that

$$\sum_p \frac{V'(p)}{p}$$

converges if $a_n$ takes on the values $0,1$ as can be seen from the inequality

$$\sum_{p\leq Q}pV(p)\leq (N+Q^2-1)\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n|^2$$

To have a more accurate study of $V(p)$ on its own, I would like to study $V'(p)$ on its own. More specifically, since $\sum_p \frac{V'(p)}{p}$ converges we have that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{Q\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi(Q)}\sum_{p<Q}V'(p)=0 \tag{4}
\end{equation}

with an unknown rate of convergence. Here is my question

> Is there are function $\epsilon(Q)\to0$ for which
> \begin{equation}
> \lim_{Q\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi(Q)}\sum_{p<Q}V'(p)<\epsilon(Q)
> \end{equation}
> With the conditions that $a_n$ takes on the values $0,1$ and the sums in (2) converge? In other words, does (3) decay at a global rate?

Comment: Does $p$ denote a prime variable in your question, and is $\pi(\cdot)$ the prime counting function? What properties does the sequence $\{a_n\}$ have?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Yes, $p$ denotes a prime and $\pi(\cdot)$ is the prime counting function. Other than the convergence of the sums in (2) and that \{a_n\} takes on only the values $0,1$, there are no conditions on $a_n$.